# DataGridView with bound DataTable - how to display ComboBox column based on values?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datatable, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` to which I am binding a `DataTable`. Let's say there are two columns. One of them is a text column, the other is a text column but should actually be a `ComboBox` column. Currently, the code to display the data is something like this:

```
DataTable usersTable = new DataTable("Users");
usersTable.Columns.Clear();
usersTable.Rows.Clear();
usersTable.Columns.Add("Username", typeof(string)); // this column is fine
usersTable.Columns.Add("User type", typeof(string)); // this column should be a ComboBox of available user types
// load the data
foreach (User u in users)
{
    usersTable.Rows.Add(u.username);
    usersTable.Rows.Add(u.usertype); // assume the database has user types of only "Admin" and "Normal"
}
// bind the data
usersDataGridView.DataSource = usersTable;
```

I want the `DataGridView` to have a column for `"User type"` that has comboboxes with the two available user types. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You need to create a new `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`. Set it’s `DataPropertyName` to mate with the column name in the table… “User type”. Then create a separate collection (table or list) of ALL the “different” “User Types” without duplicates (Admin and Normal etc…). Then use that collection as a `DataSource` to the `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`. Then add that column to the grid, then add the grid data source.

Comment: The most likely issue you will run into is that when you add the data source to the grid, the combo box column may throw the grids `DataError`. To help, you will need to make sure that ALL the “User Types” in the data MATCH one of the user types in the `DataGridViewComboBoxColumns` collection of items. Without this check, you will become familiar with the grids dreaded `DataError`.

Comment: @JohnG could you post that as an answer with a snippet of code as an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create the combo box column…We need two things 1) the name of the column in the grids data source we want to mate the column to (User Type). The columns `DataPropertyName` property is for this. 2) A collection of items we want to display to the user when the user selects the combo box.

Below, the code manually adds the items to the combo box column. In most cases you would use a `DataSource`.

```
private DataGridViewComboBoxColumn GetComboColumn() {
  DataGridViewComboBoxColumn col = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
  col.Name = "UserType";
  col.DataPropertyName = "UserType";
  col.Items.Add("Admin");
  col.Items.Add("Normal");
  return col;
}
```

Create some data to test, and add it to the grid as a data source.

```
private DataTable GetDataFromDB() {
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Columns.Add("UserName", typeof(string));
  dt.Columns.Add("UserType", typeof(string));
  Random rand = new Random();
  string adminOrNormal;
  for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    if (rand.Next(2) == 0) {
      adminOrNormal = "Admin";
    }
    else {
      adminOrNormal = "Normal";
    }
    dt.Rows.Add("User" + i, adminOrNormal);
  }
  return dt;
}
```

Putting this together...

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  dataGridView1.Columns.Add(GetComboColumn());
  dataGridView1.DataSource = GetDataFromDB();
}
```

Lastly, I can not stress how important it is to “check” the “User Types” in the data “BEFORE” you add the `DataSource` to the grid. If there is a “User Type” that does not match one of the items in the combo box, you are going to get an exception. Just a heads up.